# Android memory needed to install apk on external storage?

Tags: android, mobile, apk, android-sdcard

I am trying to install an app on a Nexus One (2.3.6) device. The APK has a size of over 100 MB because it contains lots of assets.  When I install, I get the following exception.

[2012-04-17 23:26:18] Failed to install [redacted].apk on device '[redacted]': No space left on device
[2012-04-17 23:26:18] com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: No space left on device
[2012-04-17 23:26:18] Launch canceled

I've clearly indicated that I wanted the apk to install on external storage, i.e. SD card.  When I tried to install the same app with a smaller apk size, I verified it was indeed installed on SD card.  The SD card has over 3GB of storage, which is way more than enough to accommodate 100 MB.

What is going on?  I notice when I reduce the apk size to be below the size of available internal storage, all works well; so the only meaningful conclusion I can draw is that internal memory is needed to install the apk to external storage.

Has anyone else encountered the same issue?

Edit: It is true that Google Play limits your app to 50 MB.  But that restriction is purely a limitation of Google Play, and it is not an Android apk restriction.  Amazon, for example, allows apk of any size.  You can try this by installing an apk of size 60 MB to your phone using Android development tools.

Answer (score 0):

Android applications must be less than 50MB. You can avoid this limitation ( see here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/03/android-apps-break-50mb-barrier.html, http://developer.android.com/guide/market/expansion-files.html ), but only for expansion apks.

Comment: This does not answer the question.  It is true that Google Play limits your app to 50 MB.  But that restriction is purely a limitation of Google Play, and it is not an Android apk restriction.  Amazon, for example, allows apk of any size.  You can try this by installing an apk of size 60 MB to your phone using Android development tools.

Answer (score 0):

Put the assets outside the application. On first use (or after install) download on external storage all the files you store now in asset folder.

Comment: Thanks for proposing the workaround; I am aware I can work around the issue if I need to.  Can you confirm the behavior I am seeing is real?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The way to fix your issue I suggested works - I used it. I put all the resources on my server, and when my app starts, I check to see if something needs to be download. I do this by reading an xml file with references to all the resources I need. If I have in xml a reference to a resource (image, sound, font etc) I don't have in my external folder, then I download that resource.

Comment: I agree your workaround works. My question is: judging by the behavior of Android, it seems why does the Android OS copies the apk to internal storage before storing it to external storage.  This is totally not how I expect it to work.  If an app states that it prefers the external storage, Android can then install it to external storage without first copying to internal storage.